# Как юзать VK API в Украине?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

У меня есть скрипт с VK APi. Но чтобы его запустить я юзаю PythonAnyWhere. Но проблема в том, что в скрипте есть ещё и парсер. А сайт не пропускають запрос с IP PythonAnyWhere. Как мне запустить скрипт на своем ПК?

Comment: скрипт не работает, потому что используется PythonAnyWhere или потому что VK заблокирован в Украине?

Comment: Мне надо запустить на ПК, не работает из-за блокировки ВК.

Comment: правильный вариант - отказаться от ВК. кому он нужен кроме пары стран? Использовать прокси/впн. Запустить скрипт на каком то внешнем сервере. договорится с провайдером (но тут может быть опасно), уехать в страну, где ВК работает.

Answer (score 0):

1. Используйте прокси и/или vpn.
2. Купите платную подписку pythonanywhere
3. Пользуйтесь другими хостингами, например, есть бесплатный heroku, на нем все запросы проходят на ура